# how transforms coordinates etrs89 in wgs84 with javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, proj4js

I'm programming a web page with Visual Studio and I'm trying to make a javascript to use my page. The script has to transform the coordinates X, Y etrs89 WGS84 coordinates that can read Google. I downloaded proj4js-2.4.3 to get the proj4.js and proj4-src.js files and import them into my project. Does anyone know how that script should be written?

Comment: ETRS 89 and WGS 84 are basically the same, and both are geographic coordinate system (hence not XY). Please check what you really need to do.

Comment: It's explained in [github: proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)